# How can i get the post thumbnail image src attribute?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to get post thumbnail image src attribute??
I want just the src attribute, not the full image tag.

```
the_post_thumbnail(); //give the full image code
```

how can i do so ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post,'post-thumbnail' );
```

exchange 'post-thumbnail' with your desired image size. Use

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post,'full' );
```

If you want the full size image. Let me know if this helped.